# Using Stealth QDockWidget?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt4

I'm playing with **QDockWidgets**. Here is the piece of code i'm trying :

```
def dock(self):
    widget = uic.loadUi("C:\dock.ui")
    self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, widget)
    widget.setFloating(True)
    widget.setWindowTitle("Dock ...")
    #QMessageBox.information(None,"Testing dockWidgets ...","Working or not ... ?")
```

When the QmessageBox line is left **commented** nothing works (the widget doesn't appear on the screen nor in the panel list of QGIS)

When the Qmessagebox line is **uncommented** the widget appears, title is set but widget disappear once the QMessageBox is closed ...

I fear i might be something linked with the indentation of my code but i feel i tried everything ...

Am I forgetting something ?

What should i do to have the widget remain after this piece of code is executed ?

Or could it be linked with the dynamic loading of the widget's ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`widget` is going out of scope.  Pretty sure addDockWidget doesn't take ownership of the object so you will need to keep widget alive as long as you need it or else Python will delete once the method ends.

`self.widget =`will be a start here. You should also check to see if `self.widget` is None first and only do the `loadUi` call then.

Comment: `self.widget` wasn't None but adding `self` solved the problem (of course). I shouldn't code sleepy ... Thanks